# Perform 2 Actions On Button Click Form

Tags: php, javascript, html

**My Requirement**

> Form Submission in New Window & Redirect Existing Page to a new page
>   on same click.

*When I tried only Form submission is happening. Javascript function to redirect is not working.*

**Html**

```
<form id="feedback.php" name="form1" method="post" action="feedback.php" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="SUMBIT" onclick="btntest_onclick();"/>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function btntest_onclick() 
{
window.location.href("mainpage.php");
}
</script>
```

**Actual**

> But Only Form Submission is Happening in New Window. Existing Page is
>   not redirected.

Please tell me how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML :

```
<form id="feedback.php" name="form1" method="post" action="feedback.php" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="SUMBIT" onClick="btntest_onclick()"/>
</form>
```

See **onClick**

Your Javascript :

```
function btntest_onclick() 
{
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.href = "mainpage.php";
    },0);
}
```

`window.location.href` is not a function.
And apparently it needs to be async to work.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y5SQ/3)

Comment: In your example itself from JsFiddle, Current page is redirected! Only form submission is happening. I need to redirect existing page.

Comment: Well, then I don't understand what you need exactly. In my example, both the redirection of the current page (frame of html displayed in jsFiddle) and the form's submission are happening.
I think, you don't see the redirection because it is a frame (which is redirected to 404) in jsFiddle. Have you tried my code?

Comment: Ya i have tried. thats why said its not working. Only form submission in new window is happening... Main page window redirection is not happening...

Comment: Ok, I don't understand what happened, but you're right, it wasn't working. I tried that yesterday it was working though.

So I updated the jsFiddle. I think it's working now, I simply put the redirection in a `setTimeout`. http://jsfiddle.net/9Y5SQ/3/


I've edited my answer. Hope it's working for you now.

Comment: You're welcome.
If it's the solution you were looking for, you should set it as a correct answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

add `onsubmit` to your form.
and inside function do something like that:

```
function btntest_onclick() {
   window.open("http:// your url");
   window.location.href="/mainpage.php";
}
```